# Recargar contenido de una Tabla Dinamica con Jquery | JavaScript y JSON al DOM

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, dom

Estuve intentando por unos dias que al usar la propiedad .sort para ordenar de mayor precio a menor pero en vez de recargar el contenido preexistente crea nuevas lineas y las pone (arriba o abajo dependiendo de los intentos y que codigos intente) pero dejando las anteriores aun en el DOM.

En las imagenes que les adjunto muestra como funciona y que resultado me da.

Este es el codigo que genera las tablas dinamicas antes de que se presione cualquier boton (para que aparezca tengo dentro de un $(document).ready un mostrarProductos(); :

```
const mostrarProductos = () => {
  $.getJSON(URLJSON, (respuesta) => {
    for (let z of respuesta) {
      productosv2.push(z);
    }
    for (let x of productosv2) {
      $("#fila").append(`
              <tr class="deleteProductos">
              <div class="card text-center" style="width: 18rem;" id='btnBorrarCarrito'>

                  <div class="card-body">
                      <input type="hidden" id="idProd" value="${x.id}"> </td>
                      <td class="card-title" id="${x.id}">${x.producto}</h2> </td>
                      <td class="card-text">$ ${x.precio}</p></td>
                      <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic mixed styles example">            
                          <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="agregarCarrito(${x.id})">Agregar</button></td>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
              </tr>
          `);
    }
    $("#fila").fadeIn("5000");
    
  });
};
```

Y despues este es el que lo ordena de mayor a menor y menor a mayor (Antes de cambiar el codigo del carrito (Habia hecho un carrito mediante un array pero este no me funciono y lo reforme a un json) me funcionaba correctamente con la propiedad de .innerHTML

Mayor a menor:

```
function respuestaClickExpensive() {
  $("#fila").html('');

  let productosordenados = productosv2.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a.precio > b.precio) {
      return -1;
    }
    if (a.precio < b.precio) {
      return 1;
    }
    return 0;
  });

  return productosordenados;


}
```

Menor a mayor:

```
function respuestaClickCheaper() {
  fila.innerHTML = "";
  let productosordenados = productosv2.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a.precio < b.precio) {
      return -1;
    }
    if (a.precio > b.precio) {
      return 1;
    }
    return 0;
  });

  return productosordenados;
}
```

Estos function de mayor a menor despues se engloban en una funcion principal con una animacion a parte y despues se manda al boton de esta manera (Los botones estan adentro de un document.ready que es el mismo que esta el de mostrarproductos(); )

```
  $("#cheaperbtn").click((e) => {
    filterCheaper();
  });
```

[image: Imagen de como funciona el codigo]

[image: Imagen de como lo genera]

En resumen, quiero que quede unicamente lo nuevo que es lo ordenado.

Intente lo siguiente y alguna cosa mas puede que me haya olvidado pero intentado.

$("#fila").empty();

Hacer una funcion a parte y despues llamarla que tenga la propiedad de empty()

Use Native JavaScript to generate the code.

$("#fila").remove(); Esto me eliminaba todo el contenido pero no me lo volvía a generar

Cambiar el tag de fila por uno que este en un orden superior (Es decir el colocar el div en el que esta adentro #fila) pero como obviamente no se me generaba de nuevo el div el contenido se eliminaba.

$("#fila tr").remove();

---

Otros intentos:

, en el boton que filtra de mayor a menor añadi lo siguiente:

```
function respuestaClickExpensive() {
  fila.replaceChildren();      // <--- aca es lo que me comentaste


  let productosordenados = productosv2.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a.precio > b.precio) {
      return -1;
    }
    if (a.precio < b.precio) {
      return 1;
    }
    return 0;
  });

  return productosordenados;


}
```

Y tambien probe a añadirlo directamente al boton la otra opcion

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  console.log("Estamos ready");

  // Botones - Filtrar Mas caro - Mas Barato
  $("#cheaperbtn").click((e) => {
    filterCheaper();
  });
    mostrarProductos();
  $("#expensivebtn").click((e) => {
    filterMoreExpensive();
    fila.replaceChildren();
  });
```

Pero no tuvo efecto, probe para ver si era algo incompatible o similar y en vez de usar fila coloque un div que estaba en una jerarquia superior y lo borro correctamente pero no lo genere.

adjunto el Fragmento del HTML tambien. Quizas el error esta en eso

```
       ´´     <div id="div11">
                <table class="table table-bordered container-fluid 
                            centergrid" 
              id="tableProduct">
          <tbody>
        <tr id="fila">
         </tr>
       </tbody>

     </table>

    </div> ´´
```

Lo que note, no se si es algo de relevancia, pero hice una prueba con la parte de.

fila.replaceChildren(); que le añadi dentro del parentesis mostrarProductos y me lo cargo fuera de la tabla.

---

@Orici
Probe a hacer lo que me comentaste, en el boton que filtra de mayor a menor añadi lo siguiente:

```
function respuestaClickExpensive() {
  fila.replaceChildren();      // <--- aca es lo que me comentaste


  let productosordenados = productosv2.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a.precio > b.precio) {
      return -1;
    }
    if (a.precio < b.precio) {
      return 1;
    }
    return 0;
  });

  return productosordenados;


}
```

Y tambien probe a añadirlo directamente al boton la otra opcion

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  console.log("Estamos ready");

  // Botones - Filtrar Mas caro - Mas Barato
  $("#cheaperbtn").click((e) => {
    filterCheaper();
  });
    mostrarProductos();
  $("#expensivebtn").click((e) => {
    filterMoreExpensive();
    fila.replaceChildren();
  });
```

Pero no tuvo efecto, probe para ver si era algo incompatible o similar y en vez de usar fila coloque un div que estaba en una jerarquia superior y lo borro correctamente pero no lo genere.

Te adjunto el Fragmento del HTML tambien.
Quizas el error esta en eso

```
       ´     <div id="div11">
  <table class="table table-bordered container-fluid centergrid" id="tableProduct">
    <tbody>
      <tr id="fila">
      </tr>
    </tbody>

  </table>

</div> ´
```

Lo que note, no se si es algo de relevancia, pero hice una prueba con la parte de.

fila.replaceChildren(); que le añadi dentro del parentesis mostrarProductos y me lo cargo fuera de la tabla.

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que puedes ordenar correctamente las filas y generarlas en ese orden.

Si tienes una serie de filas en una tabla y al generar nuevas filas estas se adjuntan a las anteriores es porque no estas borrando el contenido original.

Debes obtener del DOM el contenedor padre de tus filas y añadir las nuevas filas de forma que reemplacen al contenido preexistente, por poner un ejemplo con Vainilla JS:

```
const table = document.querySelector('table#table_id');

// Para añadir una nueva fila:
table.appendChild(fileNode);
```

ésto tiene el mismo efecto que tratas de evitar, es decir estas añadiendo un elemento a tu tabla, no reemplazando el contenido original.

Para [reemplazar todos los nodos hijos](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/replaceChildren) de tu nodo `table`:

```
// Sin argumentos se eliminan todos los hijos
container.replaceChildren();
```

También podrías añadir los nuevos nodos hijos directamente:

```
container.replaceChildren(...arrChildNodes);
```

Otra forma de remover los hijos de un nodo, uno a uno:

```
while (table.firstChild) {
    table.firstChild.remove();
}
```